# Batch file that checks FTP folder if any file matching a mask exist

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, ftp

I need to create a batch file that goes to a protected FTP site, checks if a file type (`*.txt`) exists, and if it does, proceed to the next step, if not, return a 0 and end the job.

I've done extensive searching and couldn't find any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a trivial task, particularly if you need to check for a file matching a mask (not for a specific file).

You can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting):

```
@echo off

set REMOTE_PATH=/home/user/*.txt
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://user:password@host/" ^
    "option failonnomatch on" ^
    "ls %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo File(s) matching %REMOTE_PATH% exist
rem Do something
exit 0

:error
echo Error or no file matching %REMOTE_PATH% exists
exit 1
```

The above code is from the WinSCP article on [Checking file existence](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I ran the above batch as:

"@echo off

set REMOTE_PATH=/Staging/nononsense-tasks/OrdersOut/nn_OrdersOut_*.txt
winscp.com /command ^
    "option batch abort" ^
    "open ftp://username:password@host:990/" ^
    "option failonnomatch on" ^
    "ls %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo File(s) matching %REMOTE_PATH% exist
exit 0

:error
echo Error or no file matching %REMOTE_PATH% exists
exit 1"

with my username, password and host in place and it returns no files exist, when there are files. Any suggestions?

Comment: You seem to be using TLS implict encryption. For that the `open` command needs to look like: `open ftps://username:password@host/ -implicit`